# Joining 2 tables and getting data from T1 that doesn't have a match in T2

Tags: mysql, join

First let me say thank you for your help and this is probably really simple and I'm just being a dummy

I have a table 'users' with fname, lname, usersnumber, active, shift
I have a second table 'checkin' with userID, dateandtime.

I'm trying to get a list of everyone that hasn't checked in in the last 8 hours. I have done that but only if they have checked in at least once in the past. If they are a new user I can't figure out how to get them to show up.

Query that I have so far:

```
SELECT u.lname, u.fname, u.usersnumber FROM users u
LEFT JOIN checkin c
on u.usersnumber = c.usersnumber
WHERE u.active = 'Yes' and u.shift = 'Day' 
AND  c.dateandtime < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -8 HOUR)
ORDER By lname;
```

Comment: this query is *so* close to being a demonstration of an antijoin.  only a couple of small tweaks are needed. an antijoin takes a bit to get the brain wrapped around. its only simple *after* we have understanding of how the pattern works  (see my answer)

Comment: Thank you to everyone for the overwhelming response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use `not exists` for this:

```
select u.*
from users u
where 
    u.active = 'Yes'
    and u.shift = 'Day'
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from checkin c 
        where 
            c.usersnumber = u.usersnumber
            and u.dateandtime >= now() - interval 8 hour
    )
order by u.lname
```

The correlated subquery checks whether the given user has any row in `checkin` during the last 8 hours, and `not exists` ensures that there is none.

This solution is usually equally or more efficient than a `join`, especially with the right index in place - here, that would be `checkin(usersnumber, dateandtime)`.

Comment: Would adding `LIMIT 1` to the subquery speed it up even further since it only has to return one row to satisfy `EXISTS`?

Comment: @kmoser: I don't think so. The concept of `EXISTS` is to check whether the subquery returns *something* (no matter how many rows), so `limit1` does not make a lot of sense. I would expect the query planner to optimize it away anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Below query should work:

```
SELECT u.lname, u.fname, u.usersnumber FROM users u
LEFT JOIN checkin c
on u.usersnumber = c.usersnumber 
AND  c.dateandtime between INTERVAL '-8' hh +SYSTIMESTAMP and SYSTIMESTAMP
WHERE u.active = 'Yes' and u.shift = 'Day' and  c.usersnumber is null
ORDER By lname;
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition `c.dateandtime < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -8 HOUR)` will get users whose last check-in time was more than 8 hours ago, but for those who have *never* checked in, `c.dateandtime` will be `NULL`, so you have to consider that condition as well.

Also, you need to take into account that a user who has checked in more than 8 hours ago might have also checked in less than 8 hours ago, so you really only want the most recent check-in date, which is why I'm using `MAX()`.

```
SELECT u.lname, u.fname, u.usersnumber FROM users u
LEFT JOIN checkin c
on u.usersnumber = c.usersnumber
WHERE
    u.active = 'Yes' and u.shift = 'Day' 
    AND
    (
      MAX(c.dateandtime) < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -8 HOUR) OR c.dateandtime IS NULL             
    )
ORDER By lname;
```

Comment: The `OR` condition can sometimes wreak havoc with the execution plan. A much better option would be to relocate the condition on `dateandtime` column up into the ON clause of the outer join, and then add a condition to the WHERE clause that excludes rows from users that had matching row(s) from checkin...  e.g. `WHERE c.usersnumber IS NULL AND u.active = `

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for an *anti-join* pattern.

We start with an outer join. Return all of whatever (in your case, users) along with matching whatever (in your case, checkin). In the case of a user row that doesn't have any matching checkin row, the outer join returns the user row without the login row. Actually, what MySQL does (or one way to think about what it does) is it invents a matching bogus `checkin` row that consists of all NULL values, that serves as a placeholder for a matching row.

If we can get our brain wrapped around that, we are ready for the trick.

We include a condition in the `WHERE` clause that *excludes* all rows that had a matching row from checkin. Leaving only rows that have a bogus invented matching row.

We can distinguish those by checking a column from the checkin table that we know will not be NULL for any valid matching row, but will be NULL for rows that didn't have a match.

---

Your query is *so* close.

One small problem is the condition on `c.dateandtime` which is requiring the value of the column to be non-NULL. That is rendering the outer join equivalent to an inner join. (Any bogus invented checkin row is going to have a NULL value for the column, and can't possibly satisfy that condition in the WHERE clause.)

So relocated that condition up into the `ON` clause of the outer join.

And to turn the query into anti-join, we can add a condition that requires `usersnumber` from the checkin row to be NULL.  (Any valid matching row would have a non-NULL value, we are guaranteed that because the column had to be non-NULL to satisfy the `=` condition in the ON clause.)

Something like this:

```
SELECT u.lname
     , u.fname
     , u.usersnumber
  FROM users u
    -- anti-join exclude rows that have a matching row in checkin
  LEFT
  JOIN checkin c
    ON c.usersnumber = u.usersnumber
   AND c.dateandtime >= NOW() + INTERVAL -8 HOUR
 WHERE c.usersnumber IS NULL
    -- 
   AND u.active = 'Yes' 
   AND u.shift  = 'Day' 
 ORDER
    BY u.lname
```

There are other query patterns that will give an equivalent result.

Some it easier to get the brain wrapped around a NOT EXISTS with a correlated subquery. This is sometimes not as performant as the anti-join pattern (suitable availabe indexes are mandatory for performance on large sets)

```
SELECT u.lname
     , u.fname
     , u.usersnumber
  FROM users u
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
           ( SELECT 1
               FROM checkin c
              WHERE c.usersnumber = u.usersnumber
                AND c.dateandtime >= NOW() + INTERVAL -8 HOUR
           )  
   AND u.active = 'Yes' 
   AND u.shift  = 'Day' 
 ORDER
    BY u.lname
```

---

EDIT:  changed < to >= to return users that do not have checkin within the past eight hours

Comment: if the condition for a matching row in checkin is within the past 8 hours, we need to look for rows with c.dateandtime ***greater than*** now minus 8 hours

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it unless someone can see something wrong with it

```
SELECT u.lname, u.fname, u.usersnumber FROM users u
LEFT JOIN checkin c
on u.usersnumber = c.usersnumber
WHERE u.active = 'Yes' and u.shift = 'Day' 
AND  (c.dateandtime < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -8 HOUR)
OR c.dateandtiime IS NULL)
ORDER By lname;
```

credit to my co-worker Joe

Comment: the `OR` condition can wreak havoc with performance with large sets. a much better pattern would be to relocate the condition on c.dateandtime to the ON clause, and then add a condition in the WHERE clause to exclude matching rows. (See my answer. Also note that there is one subtle difference with this pattern, in the more general case where dateandtime column from checkin could have a NULL value, this query pattern would return those as matching rows... a somewhat subtle but sometimes important distinction.)

Comment: Nope, my answer  didnt work when there are multiple older records for the same person

Comment: -"nope that didnt work"  - what didn't work? the query in this answer, or the anti-join pattern as demonstrated in my answer? the antijoin pattern would definitely work.... remove all reference(s) to c.dateandtime from the WHERE clause, add the `c.dateandtime < ` condition to the ON clause, and then add a condition to the WHERE clause that requires a NULL value in an expression that is guaranteed to be non-NULL on a matching row from checkin... that would definitely work to return rows from user that don't have a matching row found in checkin.

Comment: My join to begin with doesnt work for what I want, it gives me the same person 3 times if there is 3 previous check-ins that are more than 8 hours ago

Comment: try rewriting it as an anti-join... the original query is *so* close... it smells of being right... only needs a couple tweaks.  the key is understanding the exact tweaks that are needed, and more importantly *why* those tweaks are needed, what makes the antijoin pattern work. Then you will have the antijoin tool in the SQL toolbelt next time you need it